# Formatação de data funciona no Chrome e não funciona no Internet Explorer, ou vice-versa, com MVC C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, validação, navegador-de-internet

Se eu uso no modelo

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}")]
public DateTime data { get; set; }
```

Funciona perfeitamente no I.E. mas não funciona no `Chrome`. Quando abro o formulário edit, ao invés de aparecer a data, aparece `dd/mm/yyyy`. Eu consigo editar e a alteração é salva. Mas o valor não carrega no formulário de edição quando aberto.

Se eu mudo para

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime data { get; set; }
```

Aí funciona perfeitamente no `Google Chrome`, mas no `I.E`. aparece a data como `2015-08-10`, por exemplo...

Como eu posso fazer para funcionar igualmente nos dois navegadores, com o formato `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Se eu uso

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
```

gera o erro: System.FormatException: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.

Se eu utilizar Html.TextBoxFor ao invés de Html.EditorFor  funciona nos dois... o problema é que fica com hora, no formato. Ex: "15/06/2015 00:00:00"

Se eu uso

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

resolve o problema no Internet Explorer... mas no Chrome exibe dd/mm/aaaa

Não sei mais o que fazer... alguém tem uma solução eficiente?

Obrigado!

Comment: [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]

Comment: Você está usando `Html.EditorFor` ou `Html.TextBoxFor`?

Comment: Dá uma olhada no HTML final que está sendo gerado, provavelmente o MVC está gerando algum tipo de `<input type="date">` que não é suportado pelo Internet Explorer.

Comment: Vanderson, [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")] gera o erro: System.FormatException: A cadeia de caracteres de entrada não estava em um formato incorreto.

Comment: Cigano, eu estava usando EditorFor... com a dica do Vanderson e utilizando Html.TextBoxFor funcionou nos dois... o problema é que ficou com hora no formato. Ex: "15/06/2015 00:00:00"

Comment: Wedney... realmente tem um type=date no Html final... como eu posso evitar isso?

Comment: @FelipeBulle o atributto `type` do seu campo no `Chrome` fica como date? Se a resposta for sim, esse é o problema. A mascara do campo sobrepõe o valor quando ele não está no formato que o campo aceita. Por exemplo, se a data for `01/02/2016` ela deve ser passada para o campo com o atributo `type=date` no formato americano `02-01-2016`. Talvez no `IE` ele entenda por não ser compreender o `type=date`e interpretar como `type=text`

Answer (score 1):

Tente:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
```

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor a solução? Como este código responde a pergunta? O que ele faz?

Comment: developer033, esta alternativa resolve o problema no Internet Explorer... mas no Chrome exibe dd/mm/aaaa